# Is this an NEMA L6-30R Plug?

Tags: ups, electrical-power

My employer just bought a building with a decent server room.  Before I go out and spend some money on a UPS, I want to confirm that this is actually an NEMA L6-30R (sorry for the poor image).  I've been looking online to try and match the plug and I *think* i'm right, but i just want to confirm.

[image]
Assuming it is, is the APC Smart-UPS RT 5000VA 208V (SURTD5000XLT) my only option (I'd like to stay with APC)?  I don't have near the equipment that they did, so is there another alternative to keep my costs low?  Would a step-down be worth it?

Comment: I did find the APC Smart-UPS RT 3000VA Rack Tower 208V (SURTD3000RMXLT3U) which will probably be a better option (and cheaper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text around the edges reads `30A 250V`. And that certainly looks like a 2-pole with neutral locking NEMA plug. It being 250V, that makes it a L6-30 of some kind.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it is a NEMA L6-30R, but it is easy to test. Go to Home Depot and buy a NEMA L6-30R plug and plug it in.

You also may want to have an electrician come in and test the plugs and confirm to what panel and breakers they are connected. It won't cost much, and will make you sleep better.  Bad power makes IT life terrible.

I agree with the APC recommendation .. they are great units.

Good luck.